# How to remove specific "<div>" in ckeditor on enter key press or not allowed in specific condition?

Tags: html, drupal, ckeditor

I am using "insyoutube" CKeditor in Drupal website with CKeditor module. Whenever I am adding a video in the body with the help of CKeditor then it will add some class and button, which runs perfectly but the problem is:

when I am trying to press "Enter Key" that time

```
  <div class="ins-youtube-link">&nbsp;</div>
```

this extra div is added (which is the Youtube play button) the image moves down continuously and I'm not able to remove these extra divs.

Answer (score 0):

Why add a video to the CKeditor?
Why not make a field? (https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field)

If you need to always insert in different places, you can use `token_filter` module.

Maybe you insert a frame? It is not good.